# Hide mobile keyboard for specific input when scanning

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, mobile

What can be done to hide mobile keyboard input for a specific field while user is scanning bar-codes from a bar-code slip.Tried using read-only method but it will not allow to input anything thou it stops keyboard popping.

So, what i am trying to achieve is user touches specific input field from mobile and then starts scanning bar-code from a slip this time user must be able to see what he has scanned without popping up mobile keyboard.

[Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335834/how-can-i-hide-the-android-keyboard-using-javascript)

[Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28254100/disable-android-ios-keyboard-on-specific-input-fields)

Comment: you can use from this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-android-soft-keyboard

Comment: I need it using js or jquery ..

Comment: this one????
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24908049/hide-virtual-keyboard-on-mobile-with-jquery-javascript-mobiscroll

Comment: Same results...